# Converting Text Files into Excel Table

Tags: python

Need help on how to convert multiple lines in txt file to excel table format

```
Input (txt file)
ManagedElement=BSB13,BscFunction=1,BscM=1,GeranCellM=1,GeranCell=G59218,PowerControl=1,PowerControlDownlink=1
bsPwr : 43
bsPwrBDec : 430
bsPwrMin : -20
bsPwrTDec : 430
bsRPwrOffset : 16
bsTxPwr : 43
dBtsPcState : INACTIVE
dlPcE : INACTIVE
dlPcE2a : INACTIVE
dlPcG : INACTIVE
dtxD : ON
initDlPcE : 0
```

Output (Excel table)

[image: 1]

Comment: Try to import xlwt

Comment: Parsing the txt file will prob require a custom parser. If you parse it into a  pandas.DataFrame, you can then use pandas.DataFrame.to_excel

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you would first need to parse out the values and column names. Once you have done so, you can use the `pandas` library for additional data munging if necessary.

The example below assumes you have already read your text file, shown below in `text`.

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''ManagedElement=BSB13,BscFunction=1,BscM=1,GeranCellM=1,GeranCell=G59218,PowerControl=1,PowerControlDownlink=1
bsPwr : 43
bsPwrBDec : 430
bsPwrMin : -20
bsPwrTDec : 430
bsRPwrOffset : 16
bsTxPwr : 43
dBtsPcState : INACTIVE
dlPcE : INACTIVE
dlPcE2a : INACTIVE
dlPcG : INACTIVE
dtxD : ON
initDlPcE : 0'''

lines = text.split('\n')

first_line = lines[0]
first_line_headers = [i.split('=')[0] for i in first_line.split(',')]
first_line_values = [i.split('=')[1] for i in first_line.split(',')]

other_lines = lines[1:]
other_lines_headers = [i.split(':')[0].strip() for i in other_lines]
other_lines_values = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in other_lines]

headers = first_line_headers + other_lines_headers
values = first_line_values + other_lines_values

df = pd.DataFrame([values], columns = headers)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

If you have many files you can try wrapping the parsing method above into a function and loop them over.